# Finding $E[X^2]$ for $X \sim Bin(25,0.61)$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value

I got something rather new and I just wanted to make sure my way of thinking in this field is fine. Suppose $$X\sim Bin(25,0.61)$$ and we are asked to find: $E[X^2]$.
So basically I treat this binomial variable as a sum of 25 Bernoulli variables where: $$X_i=\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & p=0.61\\ 
0 & p=0.39
\end{Bmatrix}$$
So if I got it right, the fact I've got a binomial variable that I split into Bernoulli variables kind of gives me the privellege to "ignore" the sqaure part and: $$E[X^2] = E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{25}{}E[X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{25}0.61\times1 = np = 25\times 0.61 = 15.25$$
Is that a valid move / assumption since we're talking about a binomial variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is not correct.

$X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)\iff X=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i,$ where $Y_i\stackrel{iid}{\sim} \text{Bernoulli}(p).$ In this case $n=25$ and $p=0.61.$

$X\neq X^2$ since $X$ could be neither $0$ nor $1.$ The Bernoulli random variables $Y_i$ are $0$ or $1,$ and so $Y_i=Y_i^2.$

Note that $X^2=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i^2+\underset{i\neq j}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}}Y_iY_j=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i+\underset{i\neq j}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}}Y_iY_j.$

Now $Y_i$ are iid, $\mathbb{E}(Y_i)=p,$ and so  $\underset{i\neq j}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}}\mathbb{E}(Y_iY_j)=n(n-1)\mathbb{E}(Y_i)\mathbb{E}(Y_j)=n(n-1)p^2,$ which gives

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2)=np+n(n-1)p^2=238.51$$

Comment: thanks for the informative answer, in this case $X_iX_j$ is a way to consider all possible j's for each i? for i=1 we get $j∈[2,25]$ so we calculate them seperately? and the $E[X_i^2]$ is the scenario where they are identical?

Comment: I think you mean $Y_iY_j?$ Yes, these terms come out when expanding the square. The scenarios you write are correct.

Comment: Im sorry, but I still dwell on that feature of Bernoulli variable.

Comment: When I had $Y_i^2$ I imagined in like a table of $i \times i$ so I can tell that the Main diagonal represents the part of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i^2}$ but I cant get the deep meaning of the other cubics of the table.
I know that for each $i$ there are $n-1$ possible values for $j$ but doest the fact the $j$ can be zero have any influence? some of those products are probably gonna be zero so I just look at it like a combinatorics problem where I have $n \ times (n-1)$ values, and their expectation is $p^2$ because it's now twice as rare to get both of the varaibles to rqual 1?

Comment: I guess my question on other terms is: what is the real difference (or why is there one) between $Y_{i,i}$ and $Y_{i,j}$ and why the latter is twice as rare?

Comment: $Y_i^2=Y_i=\text{Indicator}(\text{ success in }i^{\text{th}}\text{ trial}),$ $Y_iY_j=\text{Indicator}(\text{ success in both }i^{\text{th}}\text{ and }j^{\text{th}}\text{ trials}).$ If $i\neq j,$ the event indicated by $Y_iY_j$ is less probable than that of $Y_i.$

Answer (score 1):

We cannot simply ignore the square, but you have a part of the answer.  If we have $X = \sum_{i=1}^{25}X_{i}$ where $X_{i} \sim Ber(0.61)$, then

$$X^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^{25}X_{i})^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{25}X_{i}^2 + 2\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 25} X_{i}X_{j}.$$

By linearity of expectation, we have

$$E(X^2) = \sum_{i=1}^{25}EX_{i}^2 + 2 \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 25} E(X_i X_j).$$

Since $X_{i}$ is Bernoulli, we can "ignore" the square for $EX_i^2$.  So

$$\sum_{i=1}^{25}EX_{i}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{25}EX_{i} = 15.25.$$

But you still need to calculate the second part above.  Since the $X_i$ are independent, we have $E(X_i X_j) = EX_i EX_j$.  How to finish?

Comment: I kind of get where you going with the second part, but only partially. you treat it in a way like $(a+b)^2$ but I dont really see how to deal with the other part since it's probably the zero part. Can you explain at least why should I get that second part?

Comment: An important property of the Binomial random variable as a sum of identical Bernoulli's is that the Bernoulli's are *independent*.  So $E(X_i X_j) = E(X_i)E(X_j)$.  The second part is definitely nonzero.  Can you finish?

Comment: If the other comment wasnt as fast i would have completed it correctly thanks to your hint. thanks!

Comment: in this case $X_iX_j$ is a way to consider all possible j's for each i?
for $i=1$ we get $j \in [2,25]$ so we calculate them seperately? and the $EX_i^2$ is the scenario where they are identical?